# laravel 5.7 nested sets

Tags: laravel, nested-sets

I tried to seed nested set with array with Laravel 5.7 and https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset package but always getting :

**Array to string conversion error** when function gets to main node children.
I am testing on example provided on github and cannot make it create tree with nested nodes from array when seeding.

```
$node = Category::create([
    'name' => 'Foo',

    'children' => [
        [
            'name' => 'Bar',

            'children' => [
                [ 'name' => 'Baz' ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
]);
```

Can anyone suggest how can I seed the database table or some other package like baum which is working with laravel 5.7 ?

Thank you !

Comment: 1) Have you followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset#installation)? 2) Is your data correspond to your relationship ?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Yes, I followed the instructions and  model corresponds with relationship - I can even seed nodes without children, for example :
$node = Category::create([
    ['name' => 'Foo',],
    ['name' => 'Baz',],
]);

When array have 'children' then it breaks.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: It's trying to convert your array to a string. That mean, somehow, `children` is not seen as a node. I don't think we can help you more without the rest of your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I succeed to make this work, so for laravel 5.7 here are the steps :

1. create new laravel project, set db params in .env : composer create-project laravel/laravel nestedset
2. from nested set run : composer require kalnoy/nestedset
3. run : php artisan make:model NestedSetModel -m
4. change app/NestedSetModel.php code to:

   ```
   namespace App;
   use Kalnoy\Nestedset\NodeTrait;

   use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class NestedSetModel extends Model
   {
       use NodeTrait;
   }
   ```
5. change database/migrations/xxxx_xx_xx_xxxxxx_create_nested_set_models_table.php to:

   ```
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
   use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
   use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

   class CreateNestedSetModelsTable extends Migration
   {
       /**
        * Run the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function up()
       {
           Schema::create('nested_set_models', function (Blueprint $table) {
               $table->increments('id');
               $table->string('name');
               $table->nestedSet();
               $table->timestamps();
           });
       }

       /**
        * Reverse the migrations.
        *
        * @return void
        */
       public function down()
       {
           Schema::dropIfExists('nested_set_models');
       }
   }
   ```
6. run : php artisan make:seeder NestedSetTableSeeder
7. change database/seeds/NestedSetTableSeeder.php to

   ```
   <?php

   use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

   class NestedSetTableSeeder extends Seeder
   {

   /**
    * Run the database seeds.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function run()
   {
       $node = App\NestedSetModel::create([
               'name' => 'Foo',
               'children' => [
                   [
                       'name' => 'Bar',
                       'children' => [
                           ['name' => 'Baz'],
                       ],
                   ],
               ],
       ]);
     }
   }
   ```
8. run : php artisan migrate
9. run : php artisan db:seed

You should be able to see new table in your database properly seeded.

```
1   Foo 1   6       2018-12-03 16:54:20 2018-12-03 16:54:20
2   Bar 2   5   1   2018-12-03 16:54:20 2018-12-03 16:54:20
3   Baz 3   4   2   2018-12-03 16:54:20 2018-12-03 16:54:20
```